# Update / change the rawValue of a enum in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, enums

Taking the below enum for instance

```
enum Name : String {

  case Me = "Prakash"
  case You = "Raman"

}
```

Can I do the following

Change the raw value of one "case" to something else.

```
Name.Me = "Prak"
```

Add a new case to the ENUM

```
Name.Last = "Benjamin"
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Short answer: No, you can't.

Enumeration types are evaluated at compile time.
It's not possible to change raw values nor to add cases at runtime.

The only dynamic behavior is using associated values.

Reference: [Swift Language Guide: Enumerations](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Enumerations.html)

Answer (score 7):

No you cannot. Instead You can redefine your enum to contain associated values instead of raw values.

```
enum Name {
    case Me(String)
    case You(String)
    case Last(String)
}

var me = Name.Me("Prakash")
print(me)
me = .You("Raman")
print(me)
me = .Last("Singh")
print(me)
```

Comment: Ah - well I guess that solves one part of it. And would I be able to create more "cases"

Comment: You cannot create new enum cases..but you can use the Last(String) case to carry different values. You cannot create an entirely new case say case Middle(String). You have to predefine all the cases and then associated different values to it.