# Provide/Append hardcoded values to the enum cases in swift?

Tags: swift, string, enums

I want to provide/append these enum cases hardcoded values. when the application loads the values should automatically be stored in the enum cases e.g. name field should have the value of **macos** and publickey is **xyz123xyz**

```
enum InterfaceField: CaseIterable {
    case name
    case publicKey

    var localizedUIString: String {
        switch self {
        case .name: return tr("tunnelInterfaceName")
        case .publicKey: return tr("tunnelInterfacePrivateKey")
        }
    }
}

static let interfaceFields: [TunnelViewModel.InterfaceField] = [
    .name, .publicKey
]
```

Comment: Do you mean an enum with [associated values](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Enumerations.html#ID148)?

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35574928/update-change-the-rawvalue-of-a-enum-in-swift